# MongoDB aggregate - Not getting data from lookup collection

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation

I know that the data modelling is wrong. I didn't make it, it was like this when I got here.
Now I need to join two collections.
categories:

```
[{
  "_id": "5f77502b36e4460d2b90aa24",
  "name": "Category-873441698",
  "inclusionDate": "2018-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"
}]
```

and project:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1f824683630f0001d9dc7f"),
    "name" : "project-199986030",
    "categoryId" : "5f77502b36e4460d2b90aa24",
    "inclusionDate" : ISODate("2018-11-01T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2018-11-01T21:00:00.000-03:00")
}]
```

and I made this query so far:

```
db.getCollection("project").aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            localField: "categoryId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: 1,
            name: 1,
            categoryId: 1,
            inclusionDate: 1,
            updateDate: 1,
            categoryName: { $ifNull: [ "$category.name", "deleted" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

And I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. In the results it never returns the category name, is always empty for all data, and I'm sure there is correspondence between the collections.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version is it? i think your query should be work in version 5+, not sure below of 5

Comment: That aggregation seems  to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bnCB3jXs5Sc

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `categoryId` is `String` and `_id` from categories is of type `ObjectId`. So I just had to convert and it worked.
In the end, it looked like this:

```
db.getCollection("project").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      let: { categoryIdString: "$categoryId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ "$_id", { $toObjectId: "$$categoryIdString" } ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "category"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      category: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$category", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      inclusionDate: 1,
      updateDate: 1,
      categoryName: "$category.name"
    }
  }
])
```